# How to handle the FBSDK token expired case?

Tags: ios, facebook-login, facebook-access-token, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I'm not sure how to handle the case when the iOS FBSDK is returning me an expired Token. In my app i'm calling the following method when clicking on a 'login'-button.

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_photos", @"user_birthday"]
             fromViewController:nil
                        handler: etc.... ]
```

This then triggers a FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification, and I'm handeling this method as follows:

```
- (void)fbAccessTokenDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
 {

  if ([notification.name isEqualToString:FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification]) {

    FBSDKAccessToken* oldToken = [notification.userInfo valueForKey: FBSDKAccessTokenChangeOldKey];
    FBSDKAccessToken* newToken = [notification.userInfo valueForKey: FBSDKAccessTokenChangeNewKey];

    NSLog(@"FB access token did change notification\nOLD token:\t%@\nNEW token:\t%@", oldToken.tokenString, newToken.tokenString);

    // initial token setup when user is logged in
    if (newToken != nil && oldToken == nil)
    {
        NSDate *nowDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDate *fbExpirationDate = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].expirationDate;

        if ([fbExpirationDate compare:nowDate] != NSOrderedDescending)
        {
            NSLog(@"FB token: expired");
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
            {
                [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut];

                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fbTokenExpired" object:nil];
            }
            return;
        }

        [self storeFacebookToken];
    }
    else if (newToken && oldToken && ![oldToken.tokenString isEqualToString:newToken.tokenString])
    {
        NSLog(@"FB access token string did change");
        [self storeFacebookToken];
    }
}
```

}

What do I need to do for the caase that the token is expired??? I'm calling [[FBSDKLoginManager new] logOut] which sets the current token to nil. However when I redirect the user again to the login button action, the same window appears asking the user to press 'allow'. It is not asking the user to enter his password and email, which from my understanding would make a new token? Where am I missing the point? For now the user just goes in loops never loggin in...

Any help MUCH appreciated! Thnx

Answer (score 0):

- > Logout In Your Facebook app in device. In simulator go to setting  and Facebook logout
- > Or Safari browser facebook logout

Again Clean the project And run. It will ask to again login in you app.

Comment: Thnx but this is not a good solution. How should I present this to the user? I need to somehow do this programatically behind the scenes, not tell the user to go to the fb app and logout...